# IIS path logic (How to redirect / display page based on URI)

Tags: windows, iis, asp-classic

I have a website where my customers can login. Some of them complains that the URI is too complicated. It is unique for each customer and looks like this:
http://www.example.com/login.asp?rld=213&companyID=127432

What I would really like is to have a path like this one:
http://example.com/Wallmart  (Wikipedia does this)

I´ve tryied to google but as I dont know the name of this plugin(?) it is real hard to find. What is it called?
And also, are there any downsides or problems using such plugin?

I know it is possible to create a virtual folder and have it redirect to the loginpage, but I have too many customers to be able to do that manually.

Best regards
//David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [IIS Url Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite)

Comment: Url Rewrite is exactly what Im looking for.
Big Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Redirect your 404 error page to one of you own pages : call it `my404.asp`

In `my404.asp` do something like :

```
p = lcase(Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING"))
```

p will be called like

```
http://www.yoursite.com/?404;http://www.yoursite.com:80/login.asp?rld=213&companyID=127432
```

so `p` will be filled with the passed parameter.
Notice the `?404` and original url as parameter ?

You could detect something like

```
http://www.yoursite.com/?404;http://www.yoursite.com/mycustomer
```

to let your customer use

```
htto://www.yoursite.com/mycustomer
```

use 'mycustomer' in you `my404.asp` page to look it up in a database, and then redirect to the correct login.

It's very powerfull , and after setting it up once, it can be used for many different urls.